# get the post id from the last post i were on

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form and multiple jobs. I want to use the same contact form for every job. I use WordPress.

So in the moment I have multiple jobs and each job is a single page and from these pages you can click on a link and you get the the page with contact form and then you can fill this thing out and get a chance on the job. But I want the headline on the page with the contact form to change.

When you come from the page from "JOB A" the headline on the Contactform should contain the title from "JOB A". The user always navigates from the Jobpage to the contactform and this page has to get the title from the last page you were on.

I have to get the `id` or the `title` from last page which was visited by the user. And if the user opens the site without coming from a job page then there should be a standard headline.

Answer (score 0):

use the [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/).  It allows you to add custom attributes to the cf7 shortcode.

In your Job page, you build your link to your form page with the job id (post id) as an attribute to the link.  On the form page you get the post id from the [url attributes](http://shodor.org/~kevink/phpTutorial/davida_PassVarByUrl.php).  You then build your CF7 shortcode dynamically and insert the post id value as a custom attribute which an be populated on your form.  To programmatically execute your cf7 shortcode, use [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function.

Comment: I get the idea behind but, how do i different links for one page? How can i set the links with the information?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use any plugins, use a javascript approach. I can suggest this way:

Add a custom parameter to the contact form link in each job page - ?job_title=JOB%A - pay attention the url encoding. You can code this on your job template too if you prefer. Then you just need to pull the title and add it to the link to the contact form. Then [use a jquery solution](https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/) to read out the URL parameters, and use that to prefil a field in the contact form (based on name or id).

Something in the nature of:

```js
// example.com?job_title=Job%A
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  $.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
  }
  
  // grab the job_title
  var job_title = $.urlParam('job_title');
  
  // set new headline
  $('.headline').html(job_title);
  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I get the idea behind but, how do i different links for one page? How can i set the links with the information? Becau at the moment it is like this: url/jobname and then you go to the contactform and the link is url/contactform.

Comment: Yes so you are at url/jobname. There you have a link to the contactform (url/contactform). You adjust this link -> to url/contactform?job_title=Job%A

I don't know how you added the contactform link, but you need to either manually adjust it per job page, or you'll need to adjust some code in your php template.